# PHP container can't see my app on localhost

Tags: php, docker, localhost, containers

I want to run PHP app on container, and when I to go localhost:5000, to see the website. When I run the container, I can't see the website on localhost:5000, only on 172.12.0.6:80 (I don't know what is this ip).

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
COPY ./index.php /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 5000
```

this is the index.php, if you are interested (I know its complicated):

```
<html>
<title>website</title>
        <body>
                <?php
                        echo "hello world";
                ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is how I build and run the image:

```
$ sudo docker build -t website website/
$ sudo docker run -it --name website --network mynetwork  website:latest
```

This is the logs when I run the image:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --name website --network mynetwork  website:latest

[Mon Feb 25 16:08:05.912611 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) PHP/7.0.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 25 16:08:05.912682 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Try adding `-p 5000:80` to your docker run command which should map port 5000 on localhost to port 80 of the container (most likely at IP 172.12.0.6).

Comment: I don't have enough credit to mark as answer, what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are connecting your container to your custom network `mynetwork`. Thus you need to explicitly expose port `80->5000`:

```
docker run -it --name website --network mynetwork  -p 5000:80 website:latest
```

With this you can reach container on `localhost:5000`

Another option - use `network=host` mode. In this mode you don't need to (and actually cant) expose ports but you sacrifice container isolation, because container is using host's networking.

```
docker run -it --name website --network=host website:latest
```

With this you can reach container on `localhost:80`. Note that with `network=host` you can not change the original port of the container.

The statement `EXPOSE 5000` in your Dockerfile is just for information and [doesn't actually perform port exposing](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be publisher

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! First solution didn't work, as @Nigel Ren mentioned need -p 5000:80. With the second solution I could go to localhost:80, but not localhost:5000.